# product in cart but when clicking on cart it shows empty

Tags: commerce

I really don't understand this one...
I have Drupal commerce on Drupal 7.

When I'm adding a product it shows in the cart summary just fine. but when I go on mysite/cart ...the cart is empty. It is not a browser issue I think. Any help on that odd problem would be more than just appreciate, please.

I tried clearing the cache on the server, browser ..none worked

Answer (score 1):

If you do a quick search of the issue queue for "Views results empty", you should turn up the solution: you've probably customized your shopping cart View to include a product relationship, but your test user must not have access to view all products. When Views goes to render the results and performs the access check on the View results, it won't show anything as a result.

If this is the case, my recommended solution would be to edit the View, open the advanced settings fields, and edit your query settings to disable SQL rewriting for the View.

Answer (score 0):

You may do the next variants to solve this problem:

1. check orders manage page on backend /admin/commerce/orders For all
   users (for without registration mode disable "Commerce Checkout
   Redirect") created new order with "Cart" status
2. Check View for Cart
   page admin/structure/views/view/commerce_cart_form/edit Maybe
   contains wrong settings